# Inherit properites in javascript "object"

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype

Folks, can you please help me with this questions.

```
var Module = function ( options ) {
var settings = {
    selector: 'body',
    declaration: function () {
        return{
            init: function () {
                console.log( 'nodule initialize' );
            },
            destroy: function () {
                console.log( ' module destroyed' );
            }
        }
     }
   };
this.declaration = options.declaration || settings.declaration;
this.selector = options.selector || settings.selector;
};

var Registration = function ( options ) {
   this.selector = options.selector || **strong text**;
   this.declaration = options.declaration
}
app.utils.extend( Module, Registration );
var m_registration = new Registration( {
   declaration: function ( f ) {
      return {
        init: function () {
        },
        destroy: function () {
        }
    }
  }
} );
```

My main questions, how i can inherit **Module.selector**  properties in m_registration, if we haven't need quantity arguments passed when we are creating instance of **Registration**

My realisation of function app.utils.extend():

```
var app.utils.extend = function ( from, to ) {
        var F = function () {
        };
        F.prototype = from.prototype;
        to.prototype = new F();
        to.prototype.constructor = to;
        to.superclass = from.prototype;
    }
```

---

**Update**:

If we are using these method:

```
var Registration = function ( options ) {
       Module.call(this, { selector : options.selector });
       this.declaration = options.declaration
}
```

How we can use inheritance if we really dont know from what instance this class extended or inheritance.

Comment: Maybe these variant well be good
  `var Registration = function ( options ) {
    this.selector = options.selector || this.superclass.selector;
     this.declaration = options.declaration
    }`

Comment: You can't define a variable with dots in the name! You have to do `var app = {}; app.utils = {}; app.utils.extend = function() {...};`

Comment: @LightStyle: Or `var app = { utils: { extend: function() { ... } } };`

Comment: @LightStyle: I realize it before, but i didn't show this part of code in questions

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, maybe he wanted to add more properties and defining them in nested objects can be painful :P @DmitriyFilipenko if the objects are defined before anyway you have to not to put the `var` keyword in front of that declaration!

Answer (score 1):

```
var Registration = function ( options ) {
   Module.call(this, { selector : options.selector || **strong text**});
   this.declaration = options.declaration
}
```

I don't know what `**strong text**` means in your case. But if you call it like this

```
var Registration = function ( options ) {
       Module.call(this, { selector : options.selector });
       this.declaration = options.declaration
    }
```

Or

```
var Registration = function ( options ) {
       Module.call(this, options );
       this.declaration = options.declaration
    }
```

In your case `m_registration.selector` will be `'body'`

Comment: Okey, thanks. I think this way just after i asked this questions. This is what i want. And one another. Can we expand these method? If we really dont know from what this class extended or inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Module = function ( options ) {
    this.declaration = options.declaration;
    this.selector = options.selector;
}

Module.prototype = {
    selector: 'body',
    declaration: function () {
        return{
            init: function () {
                console.log( 'nodule initialize' );
            },
            destroy: function () {
                console.log( ' module destroyed' );
            }
        }
     }
   };
```

Another approach is to put all the properties you want inherited to the `prototype` property. This is how javascript engine deals with inheritance